# DevExpress eXPress Application Buddies here?

Tags: devexpress, xaf

Is there any group dedicated in answering Devexpress XAF questions here?
I would like to reach out to the community who are actively using DevExpress XAF for Windows or Web.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Stack Overflow groups, but there are multiple places where you can  get help with DevExpress XAF-related questions:

- https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ (the official DevExpress Support Center)
- [Community groups](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/application_framework/#community) in Social Media:
  [Facebook (Unofficial)](https://www.facebook.com/groups/xafxpoxamarin)  | [Gitter Chat (Unofficial)](https://gitter.im/XAF-Community/community) | [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/DevExpress.XAF)  | [Twitter](https://twitter.com/DevExpress_XAF) |  [XAF Blog](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/xaf/) |  [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/2367509) | [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/DeveloperExpress)